# Can a single arbitrary constant be counted twice if it cannot be combined?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

For example, **c**(y + *c*)² = x³. Since the **c** and *c* (both same 'c') don't seem to be combine-able, should we consider them two different arbitrary constants? I have this confusion because we seem to combine multiple arbitrary constants if possible to get the order of a Differential Equation. This implies (to me atleast) that only those arbitrary constants count that cannot be further condensed.

Comment: No, because the relation between the coefficients is fixed.  The form $cy^2+2c^2y+c^3=x^3$ is not the same as, say, $cy^3+2cdy+cd^2=x^3$.

Comment: No you can't..You have to leave it the way it is $c^2$ is not a different constant from $c$ both are related...if you write $C_2=c^2$ you loose that relation.